# dotimes taking very long for large inputs

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

(SBCL 2.2.0)

Playing around with the `time` function, I chanced upon an unexplainable happening with `dotimes`: after a certain limit, it takes forever to loop.

For example:

- For 100000: (it barely registers)

```lisp
(time (dotimes (i 100000)
    (1+ 1)))

Evaluation took:
  0.000 seconds of real time
  0.000000 seconds of total run time (0.000000 user, 0.000000 system)
  100.00% CPU
  139,293 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

- For 10000000:

```lisp
(time (dotimes (i 10000000)
    (1+ 1)))
Evaluation took:
  0.010 seconds of real time
  0.000000 seconds of total run time (0.000000 user, 0.000000 system)
  0.00% CPU
  10,130,013 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

- For 100000000 (note that it does not go 10x the previous value, rather ~5x)

```lisp
(time (dotimes (i 100000000)
    (1+ 1)))
Evaluation took:
  0.050 seconds of real time
  0.031250 seconds of total run time (0.031250 user, 0.000000 system)
  62.00% CPU
  84,139,662 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

- For 1000000000:

```lisp
(time (dotimes (i 1000000000)
    (1+ 1)))
Evaluation took:
  0.404 seconds of real time
  0.328125 seconds of total run time (0.328125 user, 0.000000 system)
  81.19% CPU
  942,942,189 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

- For 10000000000: explodes

```lisp
(time (dotimes (i 10000000000)
    (1+ 1)))
Evaluation took:
  153.227 seconds of real time
  129.781250 seconds of total run time (128.781250 user, 1.000000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 11.651 seconds GC time, and 118.131 seconds non-GC time. ]
  84.70% CPU
  1 form interpreted
  370,698,869,379 processor cycles
  109,232,098,992 bytes consed
  
  before it was aborted by a non-local transfer of control.
```

Binary searching around the numbers, I found that the crossing over point is 4294967295, after which the loop never ends. Why does this happen so suddenly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-word-but-slightly-wrong answer is 'bignums'.  You are using a 32-bit SBCL I assume and 2^32 is 4294967296.  For integers larger than that the implementation has to do arithmetic itself rather than using the machine to do it.  Worse, integers this large are not machine integers and so, generally, need to be heap-allocated which in turn means the GC now has work to do.

The more-correct answer is that, in fact, 2^32-1 will almost certainly be larger than the most positive fixnum (you can check what this is by looking at `most-positive-fixnum`) in a 32-bit SBCL, but SBCL has support for using naked machine integers in some cases, and this is probably one.

Comment: Ah, that sort of explains everything. 2^32 - 1 is indeed the limit, and I am using a 32-bit installation. I did think of that, but I checked 2^31 instead. But why does the time taken _right_ after 2^32 increase so much that it takes forever to compute?

Comment: @mon: `dotimes` really must expand into something which is comparing the value of the iteration variable against the limit on each iteration.  When that comparison isn't between two machine integers, which it's not if the limit is not a machine integer,  it will likely be many instructions rather than one.  It would be worth macroexpanding the form to see what it does expand into.

Comment: Ah, I get it. If I am understanding it right, it would have to occupy multiple registers and coordinate them, on a high level?

Also I tried macroexpanding, but I don't think I get anything helpful from it, with both   inside and outside the 32-bit limit yielding the same values. I will look into how does it work internally though

Comment: @mon  Use DISASSEMBLE to see the assembler code.

Comment: @mon yes the code will be the same.  I'm away from anything that will run Lisp but may be it is something like `(let ((&lim <your limit>) (<v> 0)) (block nil (tagbody &top <body of loop> (if (= (incf <v>) &lim) <value-form> (go &top)))))`, where the names beginning `&` will be gensyms., and the issue is that if the limit is a bignum then you must perform a bignum comparison on each iteration, and also you know for certain that the result of the `incf` is mot always a fixnum or machine integer.